# Raspbian - Require login occasionally after reboot

Tags: raspbian, login, mongodb

I have suffered this problem for several months, i have already config it to auto login via

`sudo raspi-config`
select Desktop auto-login for GUI

But still prompt a login dialog after reboot occasionally as shown below, 
[image]

Then I have to change the 'monogodb' to 'pi', and type password to login. I don't need to enable it again using `raspi-config`, I can auto login in the next reboot.

Anyone encounter this problem before? How to solve this problem forever?
Many thanks!

Comment: If the login prompt occurs do you have to enable auto login again via `raspi-config`?

Comment: Hi Ingo, i don't need to enable it again, it can auto login in the next reboot